# Dynamically build menu structure based on page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm having some problems creating a **dynamic menu based on the elements of the page**. How would one create a menu from this?:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one child" id="first"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
      <div class="one child" id="second"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
      <div class="one child" id="third"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
      <div class="one child" id="fourth"></div>
      <div class="one child" id="fifth"></div>
      <div class="one child" id="sixth"></div>
      <div class="one child" id="seventh"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
      <div class="one child" id="eight"></div>
</div>
```

So for this i would like jquery to build a menu structure like so:

```
<ul class="navigation">
      <li><a href="#first"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#second"></a></li>
      <li><a href="#third"></a></li>
      <li>
            <ul class="sub-navigation">
                  <li><a href="#fourth"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#fifth"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#sixth"></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#seventh"></a></li>
            </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#eight"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the fiddle i've been meddling with (my attempt on making it work): http://jsfiddle.net/rt9Pm/

Somewhere along the way i lost my focus point and i'm unable to finish this little doodle.

Comment: So, you need to replace all `<div>` with `<li>`? so how will you decide which one should be a `<ul>`..? can you come up with a more specific issue or a better problem statement..?

Comment: the divs will probably contain images, content and forms so i don't want to go down that route.

basically i need to make a structured navigation that will 100% represent the div's hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time, and thought this might still be of use to you:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.createMenu = function (opts){
        var s = $.extend({
            'menuID' : 'menu',
            'navigationID' : 'navigation',
            'navigationClass' : 'navigation',
            'attachTo' : 'body'
        }, opts),
            nav = $('<nav />', {
                'id' : s.navigationID
            }),
            menu = $('<ul />', {
                'id' : s.menuID
            }),
            textProp = 'textContent' in document.body ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
            ulWrap = document.createElement('ul'),
            liWrap = document.createElement('li'),
            aWrap = document.createElement('a'),
            liTmp,aTmp,
            // defining a function to create the li-wrapped links:
            createLinks = function (el, par, prefix) {
                // if the 'par' is a jQuery object we'll use that,
                // otherwise we assume it's a DOM node and we wrap that with jQuery:
                var parent = par instanceof jQuery ? par : $(par);
                // cloning created elements rather than re-creating elements:
                aTmp = aWrap.cloneNode();
                // creating the 'href' to link to the id:
                aTmp.href = '#' + el.id;
                aTmp[textProp] = el.id;
                liTmp = liWrap.cloneNode();
                // appending the cloned a element to the li element:
                liTmp.appendChild(aTmp);
                // adding the appropriate class to the parent 'ul' element,
                // and appending the 'li':
                parent.addClass(('undefined' === typeof prefix ? '' : prefix) + s.navigationClass).append(liTmp);
            };

        // appending the 'menu' to the 'nav':
        nav.append(menu);

        // prepending the nav to the specified element (from the options/defaults):
        nav.prependTo(s.attachTo);

        // iterating over the elements matched by the selector:
        this.each(function(i,e){
            // using this twice, so caching:
            var $e = $(e);
            // if there are no siblings:
            if ($e.siblings().length === 0) {
                // we create the links:
                createLinks(e, menu);
            }
            // if there are previous siblings we do nothing:
            else if ($e.prev().length) {
                // do nothing, this is inelegant
                // but I couldn't think of a better way
            }
            else {
                // there are siblings (this should only be matched by the first
                // sibling of a group.
                // clone a new 'li' and 'ul' element:
                var li = liWrap.cloneNode(),
                    ul = ulWrap.cloneNode(),
                // find all childNodes of the element's parent:
                    items = e.parentNode.childNodes;
                // append the cloned 'ul' to the cloned 'li':
                li.appendChild(ul);
                // iterate over the childNodes:
                for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
                    // if the node has a nodeType *and* that nodeType is exactly 1
                    // (therefore the node is an HTMLElement):
                    if (items[i].nodeType && items[i].nodeType === 1) {
                        // create links from those elements:
                        createLinks(items[i], ul, 'sub-');
                    }
                }
                // append the created 'li' (above,  before the for loop) to the menu:
                menu.append(li);
            }
        });
        // I tend to return the created elements, jQuery often, however, returns
        // the elements of the original selector (which would be 'return this'):
        return nav;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.one').createMenu();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rt9Pm/2/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional (`assessment ? assessment_true : assessment_false`) 'ternary' operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement).
  - [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).
  - [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
  - [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
  - [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
  - [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`appendChild()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendChild/).
  - "[How to Create a Basic jQuery Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)."
  - [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).
  - [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
  - [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: this has an interesting approach to the problem :) thank you

Comment: You're very welcome, I can only hope it was of help to you. Incidentally, may I ask if your problem was solved, or are there any problems that remain?

Comment: In which case please do consider accepting one of the answers to your question which you feel best helped to solve your problem (not necessarily mine, just whichever you feel *most useful*).  For further information please take a look at "[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)"

Answer (score 0):

```
var $parents = $('.parent'),
    $ul = $('<ul>'),
    $li = $('<li>'),
    $a = $('<a>'),
    $nav = $('<nav>'),
    $navul = $ul.clone().attr('class', 'navigation');

$nav.append($navul);

$parents.each(function ea(){
    var $parent = $(this),
        $children = $parent.children('.one.child'),
        $anchor = $a.clone(),
        $subul,
        id;

    if ($children.length == 1) {
        id = $children.attr('id');

        $anchor
            .attr('href', '#' + id)
            .text($children.attr('id'));

        $navul.append($li.clone().append($anchor));
    } else if ($children.length > 1) {
        $subul = $ul.clone().attr('class', 'sub-navigation');

        $children.each(function ea(){
            var $child = $(this),
                $anchor = $a.clone(),
                id = $child.attr('id');

            $anchor
                .attr('href', '#' + id)
                .text($child.attr('id'));

            $subul.append($li.clone().append($anchor));
        });

        $navul.append($subul);
    }
});

$parents.filter(':eq(0)').before($nav);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sPJPr/1

Comment: i can't vote because i'm new here and i require 15 reputation but thanks a lot it works. Thanks again for taking the time to help me with the problem.

Comment: You can select it as the answer by checking the outline next to the answer. Note, only one can be checked as the answer per question (checking multiple answers simply changes the accepted answer.).